# When casting and accessing a DataContext object, why do we have to put parentheses?

Tags: c#, wpf

```
(this.DataContext as MyViewModel).MyProperty
```

In order to access **MyProperty** I have to wrap **this.DataContext as MyViewModel** around parentheses, why is that?

Why can't I do this

```
this.DataContext as MyViewModel.MyProperty
```

Comment: If you have `a*b+c` written, which operation do you think happens first? Same principle applies here.

Comment: You should not be writing such an expression at all, see the answer given by David. It should be `((MyViewModel)DataContext).MyProperty` instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because the member access operator `x.y` has a higher [precedence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/#operator-precedence) than the `as` operator. `x.y` is called a primary operator, i.e. one with highest precedence. Thus you need parentheses to enforce a different precedence.

Answer (score 1):

The correct way to downcast is to use a [cast expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/type-testing-and-cast#cast-expression)

```
var vm = (MyViewModel)this.DataContext
```

The [as](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/type-testing-and-cast#cast-expression) operator returns null if the cast is invalid, which will lead to a NullReferenceException later.

`as` is used to test if an object is of a particular type

eg

```
var m = this.DataContext as MyViewModel
if (m != null)
{
   . . . m.MyProperty
}
```

Comment: It doesn't answer the question at all, despite being how the code should have been written.

Comment: It's the question that _should_ have been asked. :)